# How to lock the home and recent button android 10?? (java)

Tags: java, android, kiosk

I want to disable the phone navigation buttons(home, recent) when one of my activities is open. It's like a kiosk mode. I tried following this tutorial [link](https://www.andreasschrade.com/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/). But now android is different as get_task or FULL_WAKE_LOCK is no longer used.
This is my class to check when a new application is in the foreground and restart my activity immediately.

```
public class KioskService extends Service {

    private static final long INTERVAL = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2); // periodic interval to check in seconds -> 2 seconds
    private static final String TAG = KioskService.class.getSimpleName();
//    private static final String PREF_KIOSK_MODE = "pref_kiosk_mode";

    private Thread t = null;
    private Context ctx = null;
    private boolean running = false;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Stopping service 'KioskService'");
        running =false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting service 'KioskService'");
        running = true;
        ctx = this;

        // start a thread that periodically checks if your app is in the foreground
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    handleKioskMode();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Thread interrupted: 'KioskService'");
                    }
                }while(running);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        t.start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void handleKioskMode() {
        // is Kiosk Mode active?
        if(PrefUtils.isKioskModeActive(ctx)) {
            // is App in background?
            if(isInBackground()) {
                restoreApp(); // restore!
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isInBackground() {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();
        for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasks) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stackId: " + task.getTaskInfo().topActivity);

        }
//        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
//        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
//        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        ComponentName componentInfo = tasks.get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity;
        return (!ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName().equals(componentInfo.getPackageName()));
    }

    private void restoreApp() {
        // Restart activity
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, lockscreenActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctx.startActivity(i);
    }

//    public boolean isKioskModeActive(final Context context) {
//        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
//        return sp.getBoolean(PREF_KIOSK_MODE, false);
//    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

This is my class to start the service via application context creation. But

```
    public class AppContext  extends Application {

    private AppContext instance;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private OnScreenOffReceiver onScreenOffReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        registerKioskModeScreenOffReceiver();
        startKioskService();
    }

    private void startKioskService() { // ... and this method
        startService(new Intent(this, KioskService.class));
    }
}
```

This is AndroidManifest. But "android.permission.GET_TASKS" deprecated on API 29

```
<service android:name=".KioskService" android:exported="false"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

If there is a way to disable the recent button that would be great. Please give me instructions, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try the [documentation for lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode).

Comment: I don't know how to use them. It would be great if you had an example.

Comment: Here's a demo app on [how to pin the app and disable home and recent buttons](https://file.lu/d/Foq) using ActivityManager. Source: [How to unpin lockscreen message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69724426/16653700) - Benn

Comment: [Here are the main and layout files so you can see how I did this](https://file.lu/d/For).

Comment: Thank you. I've done it already.